# Javascript Element Properties

Tags: javascript, html

My situation:  In my application I am creating I have a form with a few inputs and a submit button.  When I click the submit button I want to disable all input fields, while retaining all data.

My problem:  I know to disable all input fields I would just .prop('disabled', true); to all of the applicable fields. However, I noticed that when I disable the fields the data is still visible, but in code the value for that element is *null*.

Example:

```
$('#NewPolicyNumber').val('102452154'); //has value of input 102452154
$('#NewPolicyNumber').prop('disabled', true);//disables the element
```

When you look at the value of $('#NewPolicyNumber') it is now null.  I can't seem to find much information on this particular problem when searching online.  Why does it make the value of the element null?  Also, how to I remedy this, so I can have a disabled element that will retain it's inputted value?

Thank you

Comment: Could try .prop('value') or .attr('value')

Comment: Try this: `$("#NewPolicyNumber").attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle or something to show your problem ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 ... check the next section

Comment: what are you exactly looking for? From your problem it seems like you need to the 3 things:

 1. Retain data from input fields
 2. Disable the input fields
 3. Hide data in input fields from user. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for only the first two of what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Disabled" means that the input is not supposed to be included in the form submission. It's not supposed to be processed at all.

I believe you are rather looking for `readonly`:

```
$('#NewPolicyNumber').val('102452154'); //has value of input 102452154
$('#NewPolicyNumber').prop('readonly', true);
```

---

FWIW I **cannot** reproduce getting `null` back when disabling the element: http://jsfiddle.net/ympdafev/

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#NewPolicyNumber").val('102452154');
$("#NewPolicyNumber").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0nhycnd2/)**

Comment: How is this any different than `$('#NewPolicyNumber').prop('disabled', true);`? Please provide an explanation.

Comment: Code-only answers are *not* considered good answers here at StackOverflow. Please provide a description of what your answer does and how it solves the problem.